# Disable exit() on strict errors in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, error-handling

I have a Laravel application that has to integrate with a legacy external code base. I spent weeks making sure that everything worked. Unfortunately I'm not the only developer, and as the other code base doesn't exit on strict errors, they don't get fixed, or caught, until it breaks my code. And I only find out afterwards.

I need to disable exit() on strict errors. Fatal errors should still fail. A cursory google search only returns "Don't" which is obviously the best option, but unfortunately not possible in my circumstances.

Comment: you need to suppress stricts errors ?

Comment: Does suppressing them in php prevent laravel from handling them? Not sure how custom error handlers work.

Comment: Would a try/catch block solve the issue for you? Suppressing errors in general is a *very* poor way of handling things, strict errors no less.

Comment: yes, laravel will throw an exception when an error is raised, you could consider using error_reporting to suppress stricts errors

Comment: "Suppressing errors in general is a very poor way of handling things"

I agree. Trouble is, I don't have any control over the offending code and said offending code isn't exactly well maintained. Try/Catch would still fail, just nicely. The issue is that it's failing period.

Comment: have you tried suppressing strict errors reporting ?

Answer (score 0):

Add `error_reporting` line right after application initialization to `bootstrap/app.php` as follow:

```
$app = new Illuminate\Foundation\Application(
    // Laravel\Lumen\Application in case of Lumen
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
```

This will prevent `ErrorException` to be thrown on `E_STRICT`. Same applies for **Lumen**:

```
$app = new Laravel\Lumen\Application(
    realpath(__DIR__.'/../')
);
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_STRICT);
```